# I am now using approach Code First to create database from EF Core using ASP .NET Core. I want to know how to declare a property getDate() in SSMS

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ssms

I am now using approach Code First to create database from EF Core using ASP .NET Core. I want to know how to take the date time now from SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio) and get the date time now to ASP.NET Core.

I have tried to see if EF Core has anything to call the `getDate` from SQL but I only see that the `getDate()` should be called directly on SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio).

Comment: EF translates `DateTime.Now` to `GETDATE()`.

Comment: Something like this `context.AnyNonEmptyTable.Select(x => DateTime.Now).First();` ?

Comment: Checkout [.Net SQL Server Mapping](https://www.malgreve.net/2008/06/26/sql-server-and-net-data-type-mapping/) `Sql server`  `datetime` maps to `.Net` `datetime`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a current date, you can use multiple sources of getting a current date.
one would be to simply put into a variable DateNow like this:

```
your_Variable = DateTime.Now;
```

DateTime.Now uses the date of the server.

If you need to get the date attribute of a particular table out of a database, it will depend on where are you intending to use it and will require further explanation on your part.